# postgres ANY() with BETWEEN Condition

Tags: postgresql

in case someone is wondering, i am recycling a different question i answered myself, because is realized that my problem has a different root-cause than i thought:

My question actually seems pretty simple, but i cannot find a way.

How do is query postgres if any element of an array is between two values?

The Documentation states that `a BETWEEN b and c` is equivalent to `a > b and a < c`

This however does not work on arrays, as

`ANY({1, 101}) BETWEEN 10 and 20` has to be **false**

while

`ANY({1,101}) > 10 AND ANY({1,101}) < 20` has to be **true**.

{1,101} meaning an array containing the two elements 1 and 101.

how can i solve this problem, without resorting to workarounds?

regards,

BillDoor

EDIT: for clarity:

The scenario i have is, i am querying an xml document via xpath(), but for this problem a column containing an array of type int[] does the job.

```
id::int | numbers::int[]  | name::text
1       | {1,3,200}       | Alice
2       | {21,100}        | Bob
```

I want all Names, where there is a `number` that is between `20` and `30` - so i want `Bob`

The query

```
SELECT name from table where  ANY(numbers) > 20 AND ANY(numbers) < 30
```

will return `Alice` and `Bob`, showing that alice has numbers  > 20 as well as other numbers < 30.

A BETWEEN syntax is not allowed in this case, however between only gets mapped to > 20 AND < 30 internally anyways

Quoting the docs on the Between Operators' mapping to > and < [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparison.html):

> There is no difference between the two respective forms apart from the
>   CPU cycles required to rewrite the first one into the second one
>   internally.

PS.:

Just to avoid adding a new question for this: how can i solve

```
id::int | numbers::int[]  | name::text
1       | {1,3,200}       | Alice
2       | {21,100}        | Alicia

SELECT id FROM table WHERE ANY(name) LIKE 'Alic%'
result: 1, 2
```

i can only find examples of matching one value to multiple regex, but not matching one regex against a set of values :/. Besides the shown syntax is invalid, ANY has to be the second operand, but the second operand of LIKE has to be the regex.

Comment: don't know your actual needs but, if  ({1,101})  is actually intended as range, you could use range types and range comparison operators

Comment: is supposed to be an array, containing the integers 1 and 101

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 exists (select * from (select unnest(array[1,101]) x ) q1 where x between 10 and 20 )
```

you can create a function based on on this query

second approach:

```
 select  int4range(10,20,'[]') @> any(array[1, 101])
```

for timestamps and dates its like:

```
 select tsrange( '2015-01-01'::timestamp,'2015-05-01'::timestamp,'[]') @> any(array['2015-05-01', '2015-05-02']::timestamp[])
```

for more info read: [range operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html)

Comment: this somehow looks as "workaroundy" as it can get :/

Comment: i like the second approcach much more, but what will it do with eg. date or timestamp? i'm thinking of queries for the range of timestamps over a decade (between 1/1/1990:00:00:00 and 1/1/2000 00:00:00). Would that not cause 60*60*24*30*12*10 comparisons per record?

Comment: For timestamps, there is the `tsrange` & `tstzrange` types. These comparisons will always do N "inner" comparisons (where N is the number of elements in the right array; at least `any` works that way)

Comment: Note that `int4range(10,20)` does not include `20`. You might want `int4range(10,20,'[]')` in this case.

Comment: this is nice and simple - i will accept this answer for it answers my question - i would appreciate if you could also answer how i can use ANY() with the LIKE / SIMILAR TO or ~ operator i edited the question

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there are any 'native' postgresSQl operators or functions to do text comparison on a text array. you will need to use first example, or create an immutable  function based on it. it wont be really slow unless array will contain some thousand values.

Comment: thanks, i have a followup question to this, i will just leave this here, in case some of you have more time to spare ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342755/postgres-xml-multiple-occurences-efficient-search-via-indicies