# postgres xml multiple occurences, efficient search via indicies

Tags: postgresql

another postgres question:

i have an xml datastructure which contains data i need to use to filter query results.

To make this practicable at ~10.000.000 rows, i need indicies.
given the xml:

```
<data>
    <refNumber>123</refNumber>
    <clients>
        <client><name>Alice</name><sname>Allison</sname></client>
        <client><name>Bob</name><sname>Bobson</sname></client>
    </clients>
</data>
```

i can easily index `refNumber` and filter using regular relational operators. Performance is comparable to a query on a regular table and column with an index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_refnumber on table using btree (xpath('/data/refNumber/text()', xmlcolumn)[1]::text::int)
```

if i now want to filter by a clients name, i run into a problem. one `<data>` element can have multiple `<client>` elements. How would i place an index on each of these array elements?

All i found is, i can place an index on the complete array - this does not help me in finding data where "Bob" is a client, not even speaking of "Bob Bobson".

i have not yet read a possibility in any database that can handle xml data in the first place, nor have i read a single question on the topic.

This hits me as strange, as the use-case does not seem that abstract, if i decided to use the xml-features in the first place.

this question is kind of a followup to this [question i asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328723/postgres-any-with-between-condition)

If i read the docs and other answers here on SO correctly, the proposed solutions cannot be indexed and therefore used for filtering large datasets efficiently.

I don't know if the problem is as complex as i perceive it, or if i just got stuck in my way of thinking and it's quite late.

Can anyone help, or give best practices? all i can come up with is letting the application extract data needed for filters into other tables and construct the query using a lot of sub-selects.

On the other hand - why bother with using xml storage at all if one cannot query it except i can guarantee that every tag is and will always be just contained once?

regards, Billdoor

Comment: have you thought about casting  xpath generated  array on <name> and <sname> to text  when creating an array  and using usual string comparison  operators ?

Comment: i've thought of building a String like "Alice Allison, Bob Bobson" and searching for Strings. but  scanning this much records for all those who contain "Bob Bobson", which i can only do by regex, will take far from an acceptable responsetime

Comment: i mostly generate xml content, but newer read and fetch data for them. so i have only some vague suggestions how some other developers are doing this. mostly in these cases there are used  specific written functions in pl/java  , c or pl/python procedural languages which are rich with capabilities on processing xml data, based on those functions indexes are created and same functions are used in where clauses. some cases while importing xml , some key data is grabbed out and stored in some separated columns where filtering and indexing are done on those columns not accessing xml itself.